# Destructuring in typescript vs javascript

Tags: typescript, destructuring

I'm new to typescript, with a javascript background.

In (modern) js, the following is possible:

```
 let {n,s} = {n:42, s:'test'};
 console.log(n, s); // 42 test
```

In typescript I was assuming I could do the same, and indeed, according to the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#destructuring) both declarations and assignments support destructuring. Except I can't seem to [make it work](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCgJSIN4BQixiANilPomAFzUgC2ARigE4A0iadGrMYAc0QBfRAF4qtRABYATJ26IA5KgxKRAbiIkICNHHIA6UnAGYwC7FuFA):

```
let {n:number, s:string} = {n:42, s:'test'}; // All destructured elements are unused.
console.log(n, s); // Cannot find name 'n' (nor 's')
```

What did I miss ?

Comment: The code at the top works in both JS and TS.  The code at the bottom is assigning to different variables in both JS and TS, not doing a type annotation.  You have to annotate the whole object, not the destructured variables, if you want to do it.  Like [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/DYUwLgBA3hB2A0EDOEC+EC804C4IBYAmRJPAcjBCTDLQG4IBYAKFEhlgWRVTw9jywArgFsARiABOJUsjCSAlrADmaTNk54iMvACJK1XfRZA) (`let {n, s}: {n: number, s: string} = {n: 42, s: 'test'};`).

Comment: Ok thanks, I can accept that as an answer if you make one

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the above is valid syntax. If you run the above on the [TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/), you will realise it is invalid syntax. When it comes to TypeScript, destructruing works the exact same way as JavaScript.

What I would recommend, would be to provide proper typings (perhaps using an [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)) for your object, before destructuring it.

```
interface Item {
  n: number;
  s: string;
}

const item: Item = {
  n: 42, 
  s: 'test',
}

let { n, s } = item;
console.log(n, s);
```

The destructured elements will automatically infer the types from your initial object.